# How to check URL exists or not in Java

Tags: java, url

What is the best possible way to check if a URL exists or not in java?

My web Application has over 15000 pages and whenever a user hits /clicks some url, I should check if the URL exists or not(doesnt give HTTP400 BadRequest) and if it gives 400Exception, I should log it.

I donot want to use HTTPConnection, HTTPClient, Wrapper(since wrapper comes with servlets3.0 and my weblogic version is 10.3 which doesnt support servletsv3.0)

Can someone please provide me some solution. My lead is sitting on my head and Im not able to provide the solution :(

Comment: The reason why I donot want to use HTTPConnection/HttpClient is because of performance issues.

Comment: You want to check it where and why? Check whether there is an existing JSP from within a servlet? Check whether there is a 400 Code from a standalone HTTP client? Please elaborate more.

Comment: Are you using any MVC framework ? or its a simple JSP-Servlet application ?

Comment: Wether a URL 'exists' or not isn't a function of Java, its a function of a server process existing at the IP address corresponding to the URL's domain. The only way to check if the URL does indeed 'exist' is to try to connect to it. Keep in mind that just because a URL can be connected to today, that it will still be valid tomorrow (and vice versa). In other words, your requirement is bollocks (meant kindly).

Comment: Besides if you lead is sitting on your head on this and isn't capable of providing guidance to you.... Well you better find a new lead...

Comment: When a url request is made by any user a java servlet is invoked and with in that I should capture the url (this I can do very easily) and check if it exists or not. I could see that HTTPConnection is the only best way but not accepted by my senior... :(